# What url do you use when creating an Enterprise .ipa for testfligh?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I want to give testflight a try with an Enterprise build, however when an enterprise build is created within XCode a url where the build and manifest file are located msut be supplied. 
But I can find nothing on the testflight website that says what this url should be.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode will generate a boilerplate plist file containing the URL of the IPA.  The URL would be where your app will be hosted.

Since you're using TestFlight, you don't need this.  TestFlight will handle this for you.

Comment: Don't need which part, the url? So when entering it in XCode leave it blank?

Comment: A Xcode enterprise build will generate a plist and ipa.  You only need to upload the ipa to TestFlight.  Provide any URL since you're not going to need it anyway.  `http://test.com` should work fine.